# r mgcv Error in predict.gam model

Tags: r, mgcv

My testing data a my trining data have different factors levels. I try to merge levels but it doesnt works.

```
library(mgcv)
library(ff)

myData <- read.csv.ffdf(file = "myFile.csv")
myData$myVar <- as.factor(myData$myVar)
testData <- read.csv(file = "test.csv")
testData$myVar <- as.factor(testData$myVar)
form <- dependent ~ .
model <- gam(form, data=myData)
model$xlevels[["myVar"]] <- union(model$xlevels[["myVar"]], levels(testData$myVar))
predictedData <- predict(model, newdata=testData)
```

then R gives me this error:
Error in predict.gam(model, newdata = testData) : 1001, 1213,1231 not in original fit
Calls: predict -> predict.gam

Comment: If factor levels are not present in your training data, you can't predict for them. End of story.